# How to add Vue.js project into Yocto?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, yocto, yocto-recipe

I need to add Vue.js project into yocto image.
I am using devtool to create the recipe.

```
'devtool add git@github.com:LorchAW/vueapp.git'
```

Then i built the recipe and now i can see the vueapp in my target(/usr/lib/node_modules)
No i am confused about how to run it in the target?
My package.json looks something like this..

```
{
  "name": "vueapp",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "builddev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8080",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {.....}}
```

how should i run it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on integrating a `React` application before.

Once you have created a recipe for your application, you can run it on target same as you run it directly on your Host machine with `npm` command.

`npm` is already supported in Yocto, so you can add it to your final image with:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nodejs nodejs-npm"
```

and then you will find npm command on the target machine which you can use to start your application.

Comment: this should not be the correct answer as this merely includes nodejs in order to manually install the modules on a running machine. What should be correct is to do this at build time.